# 'Component exception' React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, render

I copied my code from an old project of mine so it should be able to work. However, I think when I made the new project it accidentally updated the versions causing it to go thorough an error. This is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading} from 'expo-app-loading';
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens'
//import from libraries

import TabNavigation from './Navigation';
//import TabNavigation

enableScreens();



const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold' : require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  });
  //fetch fonts from the folder so that we can style the title
};

export default function App() {
  const[fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if(!fontLoaded){
    return (
    <AppLoading 
    startAsync ={fetchFonts}
     onFinish={()=> setFontLoaded(true)}
    />
    
    );
  }
  //this will ensure that the font will always be loaded.

  return( 
 
  <TabNavigation />

);
   
  
}
```

The thing I'm trying to do is run this program and then return Navigation where all the navigation process works.

Here is the error:
Component exception
Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for complete components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from. the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up a default and named imports. Check the render method of 'App'.

Comment: Can you double check if you exported the `TabNavigation` component from your 'Navigation' module (import on line 8)?

Comment: Yes I have. @sandmann

Comment: Can you provide a demo repo with a minimal version of you code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this `fetchFonts` method
to load the fonts. If you installed the fonts correctly you just need to put the attribute `fontFamily` in any style, with the name of the font as its value, for example: `textStyle:{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold' }`
For a better understanding you can check this [link](https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4).

Comment: Did you follow the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4) to add the fonts in React-Native?

Answer (score 0):

Change your import for app Loading
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

Answer (score 0):

First, open the terminal and go to the project directory.

Second, run the following command to install the expo-app-loading module:

```html
expo-app-loading
```

Third, import the module into your App.js file:

```html
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Tested on Expo 4.9.0